# Is there a way to speed up ajax calls in Drupal forms

Tags: ajax, drupal-7, form-api

I've built a form in Drupal 7 using form API and ajax calls. A typical form item looks like this:

```
$form['wrapper']['step1']['currency'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => array(
    'USD' => t('USD'),
    'GBP' => t('GBP'),
    'EUR' => t('EUR'),
  ),
  '#default_value' => (!empty($form_state['values']['currency'])) ? $form_state['values']['currency'] : 'USD',
  '#title' => t('Choose Currency'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'ajax_step1',
    'wrapper' => 'step1-wrapper',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'effect' => 'fade',
    'speed' => 'fast',
  ),
);
```

Everything is working as should but even when the ajax call just rebuilds a small part of the form it takes couple of seconds (the throbber is working overtime :).

Is this normal?

Is there a way to speed this (keeping things the Drupal way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the ajax call is made, it literally rebuilds the entire form and returns only an aspect of it.  For instance, in your function **ajax_step1**, you are probably calling to return a certain element from the form, and display it in the **step1-wrapper** div/wrapper element.

If you want to speed up the form return, you need to optimize the form builder itself.  Which means, you might need to rewrite the form.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that it takes as long as it takes to Drupal to render the whole form and not just the part being replaced?

Comment: Yup, it needs to render everything first.